# Linux: Where are non-interactive commands logged?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, unix, logging

As far as I know, when I SSH to a box, it will add my command history to something like .bash_history. But when I execute a command like rsync and it executes a remote SSH connection,

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p1234'  "/example/" mylogin@17.19.20.99:"/example/"
```

where is that logged?

Another example might be using a SFTP client that uses SSH to connect (like expanDrive) - where are those connections logged?

**Clarification:** I am referring to logging on the remote machine. So, if a hacker ssh`ed to a box and didn't delete out the .bash_history, you could see what s/he did. But if a hacker used the rsync command instead, does that mean there would be no record of it on the remote machine? fyi - I'm trying to investigate some weird activity on my server, and checking the logs isn't turning anything up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the specific process that called those commands doesn't log them, nobody will.

AFAIK, neither rsync nor expanDrive have such logs.

Comment: i'm talking about logging on the remote machine. is that what you mean, too? See my clarification section in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: Javier is right, remove sessions that don't execute a shell like bash won't get logged into a shell history.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications let you add a switch like `--syslog` to output some operating information or debugging information to `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.

In your own scripts you can use `logger -- I WROTE THIS --` to write to syslog.

--edit--

```
        --log-file=FILE         log what we're doing to the specified FILE
        --log-file-format=FMT   log updates using the specified FMT
```

The above might help log activity.

Comment: i'm talking about logging on the remote machine. is that what you mean, too? See my clarification section in the original question. Thanks!